# Make 10 from the numbers 1,1,5 and 8 using the 4 operations, by brute force

Tags: combinatorics, r

I tried to calculate the following problem by brute force using R (under the assumption that a single pair of parenthesis would suffice).

> Make 10 from the numbers 1, 1, 5, 8. You can use the operations + – *
>   / ().  You have to use all the numbers, and use each number exactly
>   once. The operations can be repeated (like 1 + 1 + 5 + 8) and you
>   don’t have to use each operation.

I did the following and got the correct answer, but I would like your ideas for better ways of addressing that problem.

```
## Helper functions for inserting characters into strings
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string/25416334#25416334

  split_str_by_index <- function(target, index) {
    index <- sort(index)
    substr(rep(target, length(index) + 1),
           start = c(1, index),
           stop = c(index -1, nchar(target)))
  }

  #Taken from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101023.html
  interleave <- function(v1,v2)
  {
    ord1 <- 2*(1:length(v1))-1
    ord2 <- 2*(1:length(v2))
    c(v1,v2)[order(c(ord1,ord2))]
  }

  insert_str <- function(target, insert, index) {
    insert <- insert[order(index)]
    index <- sort(index)
    paste(interleave(split_str_by_index(target, index), insert), collapse="")
  }

  # insert_str("1+1+5+8", c("(", ")"), c(2, 3))

  #################

  library(gtools)
  library(dplyr)

  symbols <- expand.grid(data.frame(matrix(rep(c("+","-","*","/"),3),ncol=3)))

  numbers <- unique(permutations(4,4,c(1,1,5,8),set=FALSE))

  # Insert symbols between the numbers
  lst <- lapply(1:nrow(numbers) , function(i) mapply(paste0,numbers[i,],symbols))
  res1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))


  # paste strings omitting the trailing symbol
  res2 <- res1 %>%
    transmute(expr=do.call(paste0,.)) %>%
    transmute(expr=substr(expr,1,7))

  # positions of opening and closing bracket
  x<-expand.grid(c(1,3,5),c(4,6,8))
  x<-x[x[1]<x[2]-1,]

  # Generate x rows for each row of res2
  res3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,nrow(res2)*nrow(x)),ncol=1))
  for (i in seq(nrow(res2))){
    temp <- res2[i,]
    res3[((i-1)*nrow(x)+1):(i*nrow(x)),] <- sapply(1:6, function(j) insert_str(temp,c("(", ")"),x[j,]))
  }

  res3  %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(result=eval(parse(text=V1))) %>%
    filter(result==10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like your code but don't have a solution that improves on brute force. Just a few comments:

(1) You can eliminate your `for` loop assigning to `res3` like so:

```
res3 = data.frame(V1 = unlist(lapply(res2$expr, function(temp) sapply(1:6, function(j) insert_str(temp,c("(", ")"),x[j,])))))
```

Whether this is a good idea is debatable, but it's slightly faster when I test it as compared to the `for` loop (a difference of about 10%). Perhaps `lapply` would become more advantageous as you increased the number of digits or operations to be explored.

(2) The obvious speed-related comment is to use `data.table`. This is another change that will more noticeably improve performance as you move to a larger-scale problem since you can benefit from the in-place operations.

(3) You are working with a manageable set of numbers here, but in the future you might want to seek solutions in parts. For example, check half the possibilities and only check the other half if you don't find a solution. Similarly, you don't have to assume there's only one set of parentheses but could make the choice to check the second set if your first search yielded no results.

(4) When you know the numbers in advance or you're coding to a specific set of numbers, it might be helpful to eliminate all rows that have a certain combo that couldn't possibly be in a correct answer. For example, I'd get rid of anything with `8*5` or `5*8` since nothing you can do with the `1's` can bring that expression down to anything close to 10. Similarly I'd get rid of anything with `1/1` and `1*1` since these also can't lead to a solution.  Doing this would eliminate 1152 out of 4608 possibilities. (Note that I'm relying on standard order of operations rules.)

---

I don't feel any of these comments are super helpful but wanted to write since I enjoyed reading your code and since Code Review doesn't always give much feedback to us `R` users. Hopefully others will add more interesting things.

Answer (score 2):

In case you would want to make your code faster, I would suggest to abuse mathematical rules to make it a lot quicker. At the moment you are checking all possibilities - however much of that work is unnecessary.

You should consider that (+)1 + 1 + 5 + 8 will result in the same as (+)5 + 8 + 1 + 1. [Commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Commutativity) and [Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Associativity) are your friends. Note that I put a (+) at the front because it will make the change more obvious.

The second thing to consider is that brackets are calculated before everything else and multiplications are calculated before additions. Therefore think of the calculation as a group of calculations. I.e. (+)(a + b) * c + d is a block of (a + b) which is calculated first - within a block of (a + b) * c which is calculated second. How do these blocks help? Because of the mentioned mathematical rules any exchange of these blocks does not change the result, i.e. (+)(b + a) * c + d and (+)d + c * (a + b) are again the same as the above example. And you can use this to your advantage to check all results without checking every single calculation!

Therefore instead of going through all combinations, create combinations as follows:

---

(+)a +- b +- c +- d :

Additions and subtractions only. Put each number once in the front and use any combination of + or - at the back without changing the position of the numbers at the back.

---

(+)a */ b */ c */ d

Multiplications only. Check the same way as above.

---

(+)a * b +- c +- d

One multiplication. Choose two of four numbers for the multiplication and check all combinations of + and -.

---

(+)a / b +- c +- d

One division. Choose one number for a and another number for b and check all combinations of + and -.

---

(+)a * b * c +- d

Two Multiplications. Choose one number for d and check with + and -.

---

(+)a * b / c +- d

One Multiplication and one division. Choose one number each for c and d and again always check with + and -.

---

(+)a / b / c +- d

Two divisions. Choose one number for a and one number for d and again always check with + and -.

---

Next we have to check with brackets as well. I hope by now you have understood the principle how to create the combinations:

(+)a * (b +- c) +- d

(+)a * (b +- c +- d)

(+)a / (b +- c) +- d

(+)a / (b +- c +- d)

(+)a * b * (c +- d)

(+)a * (b * c +- d)

(+)a * b / (c +- d)

(+)a * b / (c +- d)

(+)a / b * (c +- d)

(+)a / b * (c +- d)

(+)a / b / (c +- d)

(+)a / (b / c +- d)

---

Obviously this will require a lot more code and you will have to avoid making mistakes in the individual checks - if your code works on the above example there could still be a mistake in one part. And please double check whether I missed something.

On the other hand the number of combinations you have to calculate will only be a fraction of what you do at the moment and code execution should only be a fraction as well.

Good luck with the implementation! (In case you wish to try). Let me know if something is unclear.